# MongoDB + NextAuth (v5) Credentials Provider server error

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to use NextAuth (v5) with the MongoDB adapter following the documentation here: https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/mongodb

I am using Node v 20.11.0

But I am getting the following error:

Server Error
Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'stream' module.
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/node-module-in-edge-runtime

This is my auth.ts file:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import authConfig from '@/auth.config'
import {MongoDBAdapter} from '@auth/mongodb-adapter'
import clientPromise from './app/lib/auth.mongoClient'
import type {Adapter} from '@auth/core/adapters'

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
    auth,
    signIn,
    signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  adapter: <Adapter>MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  session: {strategy : "jwt"},
  ...authConfig,
  
})
```

And this is my auth.config.ts file:

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { LoginSchema } from './zodSchemas'
import clientPromise from './app/lib/auth.mongoClient'


export default {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {

        const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials)

        if(validatedFields.success){
          const user = credentials.user
          const password = credentials.password

          const database = (await clientPromise).db()
          const users = database.collection('users')

          // TO DO --> find user in database and check password

        }

      },
    }),
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
```

However, as soon as I add the database constant, I get the error mentioned above. Just to be clear, my clientPromise variable imports the following (comes from the documentation):

```
// This approach is taken from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"')
}
declare global {
    var _mongoClientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;
  }
  
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = { }

let client
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
  clientPromise = client.connect()
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise
```

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

I tried following the official documentation, but it is not working.

Comment: can you update the node.js version

Comment: just added it (node 20.11.0)